# Transcoding error when using LibVLC.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vlc, libvlc

When attempting to use [LibVLC.NET](http://libvlcnet.sourceforge.net/) for transcoding one stream to a second, I get back 4 errors from the library:

> Error stream out main  : Failed to create audio filter
>   Error stream out stream_out_transcode  : Failed to find conversion filter for resampling
>   Error stream out stream_out_transcode  : cannot create audio chain
>   Error decoder main  : cannot create packetizer output (mp4a)

The full source of my 'mock up' can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Gb5Qf95f), but basically the [MRL](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/) is set in a PlayerOutput object.
(The [PlayerOutput class](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/#Description_of_the_modules) exists in the the [LibVLC.NET](http://libvlcnet.sourceforge.net/) library)

```
var PlayerOut = new PlayerOutput(
    ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=32,channels=1}:std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=bob.mp3}"
);
```

I have scoured multiple forums attempting to find an solution to this problem with little avail.
The VLC version [LibVLC.NET](http://libvlcnet.sourceforge.net/) uses is `1.1.9`, and I am not sure if there is a bug with these transcoding options, or simply not supported.

After I remove the transcoding module, it becomes:

```
var PlayerOut = new PlayerOutput(":sout=#std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=bob.mp3}");
```

Everything runs smoothly after this change, and I get a growing mp3 file, but this is **not** what I want to do, as my goal is to have all output streams constant to the settings above (Actual implementation will be using UDP as an output stream).

Is there something I am missing?
Or is this *just not supported* with this version?
If this is a 'old version' issue, should I attempt to 'update' the library, or start off new, and create my own bridge/interlop to libvlc for my goal?

Note, something I also found was adding `samplerate=44100` to the transcoding options, actually crashes the application vhost along with the application itself, without a breaked exception in Visual Studio. There seems to be a [known problem](http://google.com.au/?q=vlc+sample+rate+44100+error) with this particular setting in VLC, but why exactly does this affect the vhost itself?

Comment: Do you need "mux=ts"? This string works for me in my own projects: "sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,channels=2,ab=192,samplerate=44100,vcodec=dummy}:standard{dst=out.mp3,mux=raw,access=file}", but I also use latest version of VLC (2.2.x). From your error, it looks like it's not even trying mp3, and trying mp4a instead, like it's ignoring your string.

Comment: Very good point actually, I'll try that tomorrow. I couldn't understand why it was only registering as mp4a either. Even when I tried using the vorbis codec.
How are you interfacing to VLC 2.2.X? Are you using the libvlc.dll directly, or have you modded a library? (For example, the LibVLC.NET)

Comment: I maintain the open source vlcj (Java) project.

Comment: Very impressive. A shame that is not C#/.NET, otherwise I would probably be using it.

Comment: I no longer need the answer to this question as I have written a small C# library to interface with libvlc.dll "Twoflower" via interop. I will leave this question up for anyone else that might answer/learn.
@caprica Sadly the string didn't work but thank you for the suggestion.